# DVD ROM won't read DVDs Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dvd, cd, cd-drive

I have a problem with my DVD ROM drive. It won't read my CDs using Windows 10.

When I insert a CD, it sounds as if it reads it but sticks in the middle. When I press my DVD ROM disk into my computer, it says please insert a CD into the drive although a CD is already inside.

I tried reinstalling the driver, tried registry solutions, nothing worked and I am in total loss. DVD ROM is:

TSSTcorp CDDVDDW SH-222BB

Comment: Sounds like your drive is defective. Does it work with another operating system?

Comment: It is a new rig, so I didn't test it besides

Comment: The drive is bad, try another one.

Comment: "It is a new rig", so make use of the warrantee.